# How can I add form data from ASP.NET wizard into a session array object?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to add form data from an asp.net wizard into a session array object. The object should store the question number and question answer selected by the user for each question. I'm trying to use a multidimensional array to store the question number and the associated answer. I would also be open to using a hashtable or dictionary solution.

This is the code I've got so far:

```
string[,] strQandA = new string[10, 2] {{"1", Q1.SelectedValue}, {"2", Q2.SelectedValue}, {"3", Q3.SelectedValue}, {"4", Q4.SelectedValue}, {"5", Q5.SelectedValue}, {"6", Q6.SelectedValue}, {"7", Q7.SelectedValue}, {"8", Q8.SelectedValue}, {"9", Q9.SelectedValue}, {"10", Q10.SelectedValue}};
Session["mySession"] = strQandA;
```

Is this correct? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: "Is this correct?" == "Have you tried it and does it work?"

Comment: I've tried Response.Write(Session["mySession"]); and it returns System.String[,].

Comment: That's because when you call `Write` it calls `ToString()` on the object you pass it if it's not already a string. If you call `ToString()` on a ref type that doesn't have an overload, it'll write out the Type by default. You need to index into your array to get the values out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better practice for your needs is Dictionary with the question number as key and selected value as the value. Something like:

```
DropDownList[] arrDDL = new DropDownList[] { Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4, Q5, Q6, Q7, Q8, Q9, Q10 };
Dictionary<int, string> strQandA = new Dictionary<int, string>();
for (int i = 0; i < arrDDL.Length; i++)
   strQandA.Add(i + 1, arrDDL[i].SelectedValue);
Session["mySession"] = strQandA;
```

To access specific value later e.g. the third question answer:

```
(Session["mySession"] as Dictionary<int, string>)[3]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast the collection, Response.Write calls ToString() on the object and will return the default implementation.

```
 Dictionary<string, YourType> strQandA = new Dictionary<string, YourType>();
Session["mySession"] = strQandA;

Dictionary<string, YourType> mySession = (Dictionary<string, YourType>)Session["mySession"];
```